# How to implement DiffUtil for images

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-diffutils

Hello there I'm heard about this library DiffUtil which improves the recycler view performance and hence my recycler view contains images it is will be better for me to implement it but I don't know-how

> Note: I didn't include the Fragment code so the question doesn't get
> long but if you want more references to the code please tell me i will
> update the question

**PostAdapter_Home.kt**

```
class PostAdapter_Home(var mcontext: Context, var mUploads: MutableList<Upload?>?) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<PostAdapter_Home.PostViewHolder>() {
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): PostViewHolder {
        val view: View
        view = LayoutInflater.from(mcontext)
            .inflate(R.layout.post_item_container_home_ex, parent, false)
        return PostViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: PostViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val shimmer = ColorHighlightBuilder()
            .setBaseColor(Color.parseColor("#F3F3F3"))
            .setBaseAlpha(1f)
            .setHighlightColor(Color.parseColor("#E7E7E7"))
            .setHighlightAlpha(1f)
            .setDropoff(50f)
            .build()
        val shimmerDrawable = ShimmerDrawable()
        shimmerDrawable.setShimmer(shimmer)
        val uploadCurrent = mUploads?.get(position)
        Glide.with(mcontext)
            .load(uploadCurrent?.getmImageUrl())
            .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.AUTOMATIC)
            .placeholder(shimmerDrawable)
            .fitCenter()
            .into(holder.imageView)

    }


    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return mUploads?.size!!
    }

    //    public long getId() {
    //        return this.id;
    //    }
    //
    //    @Override
    //    public long getItemId(int position) {
    //        return mUploads.get(position).Id;
    //    }
    fun setUploads(uploads: MutableList<Upload?>?) {
        mUploads = uploads
    }
    

    class PostViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        val imageView: ShapeableImageView

        init {
            imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imagePostHome)
        }
    }
}
```

**Upload.kt**

```
package com.example.myappnotfinal.AdaptersAndMore

import com.google.firebase.database.Exclude

class Upload {
    internal var mImageUrl: String? = null
    private var mKey: String? = null

    constructor() {}
    constructor(imageUrl: String?) {
        mImageUrl = imageUrl
    }

    fun getmImageUrl(): String? {
        return mImageUrl
    }

    fun setmImageUrl(mImageUrl: String?) {
        this.mImageUrl = mImageUrl
    }

    @Exclude
    fun getmKey(): String? {
        return mKey
    }

    @Exclude
    fun setmKey(Key: String?) {
        mKey = Key
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an implementation of DiffUtil.ItemCallback.

Diff Util callback class

```
class PostDiffUtil : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<Upload>() {
    override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: Upload, newItem: Upload): Boolean = oldItem == newItem
    override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: Upload, newItem: Upload): Boolean =
        oldItem.toString() == newItem.toString()
}
```

Upload data class

```
data class Upload(
    var mImageUrl: String? = null,
    @Exclude @set:Exclude @get:Exclude
    var mKey: String? = null
)
```

Adapter class.

```
class PostAdapter_Home : RecyclerView.Adapter<PostAdapter_Home.PostViewHolder>() {
    private val postDiffUtil = PostDiffUtil()
    val postListDiffer = AsyncListDiffer(this, postDiffUtil)
    override fun getItemCount(): Int = postListDiffer.currentList.size
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): PostViewHolder =
        PostViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.post_item_container_home_ex, parent, false))

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: PostViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bindView(postListDiffer.currentList[position])
    }

    class PostViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        val imageView: ShapeableImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imagePostHome)
        fun bindView(upload: Upload) {
            val shimmer = ColorHighlightBuilder()
                .setBaseColor(Color.parseColor("#F3F3F3"))
                .setBaseAlpha(1f)
                .setHighlightColor(Color.parseColor("#E7E7E7"))
                .setHighlightAlpha(1f)
                .setDropoff(50f)
                .build()
            val shimmerDrawable = ShimmerDrawable()
            shimmerDrawable.setShimmer(shimmer)
            Glide.with(imageView.context)
                .load(upload?.getmImageUrl())
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.AUTOMATIC)
                .placeholder(shimmerDrawable)
                .fitCenter()
                .into(imageView)
        }
    }
}
```

To update the list. Reference the adapter within Activity or fragment and just submit list with your values

```
val postAdapter = PostAdapter_Home()
postAdapter.postListDiffer.submitList(< Your List Here >)
```

Comment: recycler view is smother , thank you so much

Comment: Hey brother, i have asked a question related to Pagination https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70096562/how-to-implement-pagination-with-kotlin can you help me out with that

Comment: it will be grateful if you help me with pagination , I'm stuck on it from last 4 month

Comment: @VasantRaval I will have a look at it.